# Selecting an amplifier - a PA or LNA that seem to have similar gains and P1db

Tags: sdr, lna

I am using an SDR that outputs a maximum power of -25dBm. I need about 15dBm to go into the Tx antenna.

I am looking at a PA and an LNA that have similar P1db points, but the LNA has a much better noise figure. I know that LNA is for receiving, but looking at the data sheet, it looks like it will be a good PA as well.

https://rfbayinc.com/products_pdf/product_1_584.pdf
https://rfbayinc.com/products_pdf/product_1_611.pdf

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you OK with DC power consumption? The designer of a PA might try to give the customer reasonable efficiency, while a LNA designer is more concerned with linearity.

Comment: @glen_geek I don't have any limitations with power consumption

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

Probably not much. An LNA with a gain of 40 dB will just be typically, as being optimized for NF rather than high efficiency, more power-hungry, unless also much more expensive. Also, I'd expect an LNA to have flatter gain over its operational frequency range.

Also, you need to realize that "PA" and "LNA" are labels that we put on our devices ourselves. I can call a 10 dB gain amplifier with a 10 dB noise figure "LNA" if I want to, nothing is going to stop me.

Comment: Both are the same price range and use about 3W. So the LNA has a NF of 0.6db while the PA has a NF of 4db. So I am not sure how to choose the better amplifier.

Comment: well, if everything is equal, choose by fair dice roll. The LNA has better noise figure, which doesn't matter as much for PA, but why not? if everything else fits... Again, that's why I wrote my last paragraph: Just because someone calls a device LNA doesn't mean you have to use it in a receiver.